# Ich fahre dem taxi zum Büro

Tags: learning

I am doing German A1.

I just want to know whether `Ich fahre dem taxi zum Büro` can be used to mean `I come to office by taxi`.

Comment: Questions, that basically ask for the correctness of a translation are off-topic here on German Language Stack Exchange.

Comment: ok .................

Comment: Well, shouldn't we help with correct translations? I admit that the question may not really specify the circumstances he/she is asking about, but I think it's generally worthwhile to broaden the understanging of beginners, too

Comment: @Kristina Current consensus (as reflected by the close reason) is that translation requests (or meaning requests) are off-topic unless they highlight a specific point of concern and show their prior work. You are always welcome to suggest a new consensus on [meta]. However, it may be unlikely to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, kind of.

There are some errors in your German sentence:

**das Taxi**
This is a noun. In German **all** nouns must **always** be written with a uppercase first letter.

**mit** dem Taxi
You have to use a preposition if you want to say, that you drive **with** the taxi. (In German the grammatical pattern `<move> by <vehicle>` doesn't exist, so you have to use the pattern `<move> with <article> <vehicle>`.)

So, the correct sentence would be:

> Ich fahre **mit** dem **T**axi zum Büro.

But this not a literal translation of your English sentence. The literal translation of the German sentence is:

> I drive with the taxi to the office.

Your English sentence would be in German:

> I **komme** mit dem Taxi zum Büro.

- to come = kommen
- to drive = fahren

Comment: Oh, I missed the word mit.

Comment: @InQusitive: Yes, and the uppercase T in Taxi!